# Exodus 15:11 Parasha Beshalach

Tags: grammar-dikduk

In Exodus 15:11 the first chaf doesn’t have a dot (dagesh) but the second one does: Mi-chamocha, and then Mi kamocha. The meaning of both phrases is the same: “Who is like you?” The first Mi-chamocha has a hyphen (makkef) linking Mi to chamocha; it’s all one word, so the chaf doesn’t begin a word, and so it doesn’t take a dagesh. My question: if both phrases mean the same (“Who is like you?”) why isn’t the Hebrew the same?